# Text is not wrapping in the tag popup of "Top Tags" section in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, popups

As can be seen in the below screenshot, it's all messed up:

[image: tag popup without text overflow]

Comment: Also on MSO: [Tag excerpts on profiles don't wrap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427027)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will look correctly in the next build. Thanks [Kyle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/718314/kyle-pollard) for fixing it!

I recently fixed a bug that had for years prevented the tag info popups from appearing in that space at all, which is why the wrapping issue hadn't appeared until now.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Rep steal! (aka why didn't Kyle posted this himself? ;))

Comment: Also on more serious note, should tags always have the full popup appear when hovered? Noticed recently some places where there's no popup (just plain tooltip) and wondered about it.

Comment: Because Kyle is asleep but pinged me on the PR 

Comment: On your question -- yeah, there are a few places where it's disabled, so it's possible.